# ReactJS dynamic button bind

Tags: jquery, button, dynamic, reactjs, bind

Let's say the code (child component called Answers) generates 3 divs dynamically (based on dataset mapped) and each div contains a textbox and a submit button.

If a user types something into the 2nd textbox and clicks submit, how do I maintain the proper binding (grab the text from the 2nd textbox) in the buttonSubmit handler (located in the parent component)?

Let's say that my goal is to see the correct text in the **alert(comment)** in the buttonSubmit handler ... how can I accomplish this? Thanks !

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

buttonSubmit: function(e){
     e.preventDefault();        

     var comment = $(this).closest('.answer-container').find('.answer-textArea').val(); // get comment text

     alert(comment);
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Answers data={this.state.answers} onButtonSubmit={this.buttonSubmit} />
        </div>
    );
}
 });
```

```js
 var Answers = React.createClass({
 render: function(){      
        var self = this;

        var answerNodes = this.props.data.map(function(answer){
   return (
    <div className="answer-container"> 
                        <div className="answer-comment">
                            <textarea className="answer-textArea" placeholder="Comment must be more than 5 words ..."></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div className="answer-rateIt">
                            <input data-id={answer.AnswerID} type="number" className="rating" />
                            <br /><br />
                            <button id={answer.AnswerID} className="buttonSubmit" onClick={self.props.onButtonSubmit} >Submit</button>
                        </div>
                 </div>
   );
  });

  return(
   <div>
    {answerNodes}
   </div>
  );
 }
 });
```

Comment: Why not have `Answers` create an `Answer` component so that the event handling? Each could raise an event to the parent as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is split the Answer markup into a separate component. The responsibility of this component will be to render the markup for a single answer and to provide the comment and rating values when the submit button is clicked through a provided handler. The comment and rating values are obtained using refs.

```
var Answer = React.createClass({
    submitHandler: function (e) {
        if (this.props.hasOwnProperty('submitHandler')) {
            this.props.submitHandler({
                comment: this.refs.comment.getDOMNode().value,
                rating: this.refs.rating..getDOMNode().value
            });
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="answer-container"> 
                <div className="answer-comment">
                    <textarea
                        ref="comment"
                        className="answer-textArea"
                        placeholder="Comment must be more than 5 words ..."
                    ></textarea>
                </div>

                <div className="answer-rateIt">
                    <input
                        ref="rating"
                        type="number"
                        className="rating"
                    />
                    <br/><br/>
                    <button
                        className="buttonSubmit"
                        onClick={this.submitHandler}
                    >
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The Answsers component will render a group of Answer components using a submitHandler which attaches the AnswerId to given comment and rating, and passes this data up to the parent through the provided handler function.

```
var Answers = React.createClass({
    render: function(){         
        var self = this;

        var answerNodes = this.props.data.map(function(answer){
            var submitHandler = function (answerData) {
                if (self.props.hasOwnProperty('submitHandler')) {
                    self.props.submitHandler({
                        answerId: answer.AnswerID,
                        comment: answerData.comment,
                        rating: answerData.rating
                    });
                }
            };
            return <Answer id={answer.AnswerID} submitHandler={submitHandler}/>;
        });

        return(
            <div>
                {answerNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
 });
```

The parent's submit handler can then access the data through the given object.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

    buttonSubmit: function(e) {
        // e.preventDefault(); Not necessary unless inside a form

        var comment = e.comment;

        alert(comment);
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Answers data={this.state.answers} submitHandler={this.buttonSubmit} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Oops, I've updated the references from `this` to `self` inside of the `map()` call in the Answers component. I haven't actually run this code so it may contain minor errors like that.

Comment: Yeah, after I changed the 2 "this" to "self" in the Answers component mapping code, it worked !  I took the liberty to edit the code by tagging all the submitHandlers. I think it'll help other beginners reading this to not get lost. I think there might be 1 or 2 syntax errors still, but conceptually, this works. I can't just copy my corrected code over because my stuff actually has a lot more stuff going on. Thank you, answer accepted ... ;-)

Comment: Holy cow, I tagged all the submitHandlers with suffixes such as AAA, BBB, etc. to HELP new programmers follow the trail. The reviewers rejected it. Here's one reason: "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive." - The other reason was that it deviated too much from the OP's intent ... I don't quite understand these reasons, but so be it ...